# Athena query JSON Array without struct

Tags: sql, aws-glue, amazon-athena, presto, trino

In Athena how can I structure a select statement to query the below by timestamp? The data is stored as a string

```
[{
    "data": [{
        "ct": "26.7"
    }, {
        "ct": "24.9",
    }, {
        "ct": "26.8",
    }],
    "timestamp": "1658102460"
}, {
    "data": [{
        "ct": "26.7",
        }, {
        "ct": "25.0",
        }],
    "timestamp": "1658102520"
}]
```

I tried the below but it just came back empty.

```
SELECT json_extract_scalar(insights, '$.timestamp') as ts
FROM history
```

What I am trying to get to is returning only the data where a timestamp is between X & Y.

When I try doing this as a struct and a cross join with unnest it's very very slow so I am trying to find another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_extract_scalar` will not help here because it returns only one value. Trino improved vastly [json path](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html) support but Athena has much more older version of the Presto engine which does not support it. So you need to cast to array and use `unnest` (removed trailing commas from json):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (json_str) AS (
    values ('[{
    "data": [{
        "ct": "26.7"
    }, {
        "ct": "24.9"
    }, {
        "ct": "26.8"
    }],
    "timestamp": "1658102460"
}, {
    "data": [{
        "ct": "26.7"
        }, {
        "ct": "25.0"
        }],
    "timestamp": "1658102520"
}]')
)

-- query
select mp['timestamp'] timestamp,
    mp['data'] data
from dataset,
unnest(cast(json_parse(json_str) as array(map(varchar, json)))) as t(mp)
```

Output:

| timestamp | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1658102460 | [{"ct":"26.7"},{"ct":"24.9"},{"ct":"26.8"}] |
| 1658102520 | [{"ct":"26.7"},{"ct":"25.0"}] |

After that you can apply filtering and process `data`.